# AttributeError: 'TextTestResult' object has no attribute 'assertIn'

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying some Python with selenium, I have some defined tests in simpleUsageUnittest.py:

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#   @unittest.skip("skip test_001")
    def test_001_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("selenium")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#   @unittest.skip("skip test_002")
    def test_002_goole_and_stack_test_test(self):
        driver_g = self.driver
        driver_g.get("http://www.google.com")
        self.assertIn("Google", driver_g.title)
        body_g = driver_g.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
        body_g.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
        driver_g.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
        self.assertIn("Stack", driver_g.title)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(warnings = 'ignore')
```

Alone this set is working perfectly, but then I am trying to create some suite, testTestSuite.py:

```
import unittest
import simpleUsageUnittest
import sys

def suite():
    testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
    testSuite.addTest(simpleUsageUnittest.PythonOrgSearch.setUp)
    testSuite.addTest(simpleUsageUnittest.PythonOrgSearch.test_001_search_in_python_org)
    testSuite.addTest(simpleUsageUnittest.PythonOrgSearch.test_002_goole_and_stack_test_test)
    testSuite.addTest(simpleUsageUnittest.PythonOrgSearch.tearDown)
    return testSuite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

And while running this suite I encounter AttributeError: 'TextTestResult' object has no attribute 'assertIn',  and since I dont exactly understand it I cannot fix it ;) If I delete assertIn lines in simpleUsageUnittest.py - then it is working again, but it is of course not what I want to do! Also [Asserts in Python 2.7 not working for me example assertIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000303/asserts-in-python-2-7-not-working-for-me-example-assertin) was not a big help since I am using Python 3.3.5 and Selenium 2.41.0. Can someone explain it to me? Or direct what attributes can I use to save my assert? ;)

Full trace:

```
C:\Users\zzz\Python\selenium_tutorial>python testTestSuite.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testTestSuite.py", line 14, in <module>
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\unittest\runner.py", line 168, in run
    test(result)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\unittest\suite.py", line 105, in run
    test(result)
  File "C:\Users\zzz\Python\selenium_tutorial\simpleUsageUnittest.py", line
 18, in test_001_search_in_python_org
    self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
AttributeError: 'TextTestResult' object has no attribute 'assertIn'
```

**SOLUTION**

OK, it looks like in my testTestSuite.py, while executing, TextTestRunner treats "self.asserIn" lines in simpleUsageUnittest.py as self == TextTestRunner not as self == TestCase (I dont know if I explain/understand it correctly, but it is how i see it ;)). Here is fixed testTestSuite.py:

```
import unittest
import simpleUsageUnittest
import sys

def suite():
    testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
    testSuite.addTest(simpleUsageUnittest.PythonOrgSearch('test_001_search_in_python_org'))
    testSuite.addTest(simpleUsageUnittest.PythonOrgSearch('test_002_goole_and_stack_test_test'))
    return testSuite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

'setUp' and 'tearDown' are missing because they are called automatically after every 'test'.

Comment: Can you provide a full traceback of the error?

Comment: I added Trace in question.

Comment: According to python documentation `assertIn` is added in python3.1. Are you sure you are running python3.3 ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn

Comment: Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:37:12) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Yes I am - at least it is what i get after typing python into console.

Comment: OK I was able to solve this (solution added to description). Many thanks for sugestions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732438/run-all-unit-test-in-python-directory was helpful! Also many thanks to my friend Sebastian for help with this solution.

Comment: I posted the solution as community wiki answer so that's clear it's resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

OK, it looks like in my testTestSuite.py, while executing, TextTestRunner treats "self.asserIn" lines in simpleUsageUnittest.py as self == TextTestRunner not as self == TestCase (I dont know if I explain/understand it correctly, but it is how i see it ;)). Here is fixed testTestSuite.py:

```
import unittest
import simpleUsageUnittest
import sys

def suite():
    testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
    testSuite.addTest(simpleUsageUnittest.PythonOrgSearch('test_001_search_in_python_org'))
    testSuite.addTest(simpleUsageUnittest.PythonOrgSearch('test_002_goole_and_stack_test_test'))
    return testSuite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

'setUp' and 'tearDown' are missing because they are called automatically after every 'test'.